# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectName]]

Tags: tomcat8

I am getting following error while running app on tomcat-8. I am using Eclipse Luna-32 bit, tomcat-8 32 bit, Java-8 32 bit.

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor E:\PROJECTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\connect_afs_ui.xml
Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:connect_afs_ui' did not find a matching property.
Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/connect_afs_ui]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@146cf9f]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4832)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@1679622]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The directory specified by base and internal path [C:\Users\ravi.suthar\git\FashionConnect\connect_afs_ui\target\test-classes]\[] does not exist.
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.checkType(DirResourceSet.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 16 more

Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor E:\PROJECTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\connect_afs_ui.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/connect_afs_ui]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor E:\PROJECTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\connect_afs_ui.xml has finished in 18 ms
Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 24, 2015 6:36:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 303 ms
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did the following steps and the error removed.

```
1. Delete existing tomcat from the eclipse Server tab and remove existing tomcat directory
2. Provide new copy of tomcat in Server tab > add new server
3. Double click on tomcat from server tab
4. In tomcat overview tab, in Server Option 
    a. unselect > Select modules without publishing
    b. unselect > Publish modules contexts to separate XML files
5. Save tomcat changes
6. Add project to tomcat
7. Publish 
8. Start / Debug
```

Comment: Is deleting tomcat the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same exception. In my case problem was, **lib folder under WEB-INF was removed by me by mistake** and I started to place custom jars in project main folder and referenced from there in the build path.

After spending a lot of time I realized this mistake and just corrected the directory structure and created lib folder under WEB-INF and placed custom jars in it and referenced from there. It started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check same .java file exits in another package, if exits then delete this .java file to solve this type problem. (Eclipse IDE)